# Installing "Aplication Deployment" without the SDK (Windows Phone)

Tags: windows-phone-7, deployment

I'm working with some client on making an app. I managed to get him an unlocked device, so I can just send him the xap file, and he can directly test it. 
But I don't want him to install the whole SDK, I only need him to get the "Application Deployment" tool, so he can deploy the thing to the phone.

Is there a way to get the "Application Deployment" program, without installing the whole SDK?

Comment: if you and he are developing for Mango (7.5), why not dev the app and publish what you need him to see as a beta, sending it only to his Live ID. that way he doesn't need to install anything, other than the beta app once he receives the email. no computer connections, no confusing install techniques, no unneeded files.  i've done this, works like a charm. (note the beta app will expire after 90 days if you don't expire it before then).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you can get the "Application Deployment" program without the SDK, however there are a couple of alternatives ...

- Chevron WP7 is an 'official' (i.e. Microsoft controlled) mechanism for unlocking a phone and allowing application to be side-loaded. I thin it costs $9.00 and allows you to upload XAP files to your phone
- Windows Phone Marketplace beta, you can upload a XAP to the marketplace as a beta. This XAP will not go through the usual test processes, and will be 'live' within a few hours. This is the official way of sharing beta code.

Comment: @Stan true, but I guess Microsoft might release some in the future. Anyhow, the marketplace beta functionality sounds like the right way to go here.

Comment: The beta solution looks great. But I don't deal directly with the Microsoft app hub. Outside the US we use some partner called YallaApps. I think I can talk to them. But It really would be great if there's a tool to download the xap file. After all its just a file gets downloaded to the phone. There must be a way to do this.

Comment: @user836252: yalla supports beta distribution. see: http://blog.yallaapps.com/2011/09/04/test-an-app-on-your-device-even-if-not-unlocked-private-beta-distribution/

Comment: yea, but this process is not automated. So, every time I have an update, I have to ask for it by email and wait. 
I know this is the best answer to my question. But I was hopping to get the application deployment program. I'll just wait, maybe I get a better answer.

Comment: that's exactly the same way AppHub beta is too. for every update, you have to publish a new beta.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Windows Phone Powertools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/) might be what you're looking for. It doesn't seem to have any references to any of the SDK dll's.

Comment: I'm not looking for an extension. I need to install the "Application Deployment" without the SDK. please read the question before you answer

Comment: @Ku6opr: It is, but has dependencies on Visual Studio Assemblies, which I missed. That's probably why user836252 was so upset: I wasted his/her valuable time.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt lol I'm not upset, and I didn't waste my time, all I had to do is "read" the first sentence: "The Windows Phone Power Tools are a natural extension to the developer tools that come with the Windows Phone SDK.". I was just giving you and advise, I know points are important to you, but you gotta earn them ;)

Comment: @user836252: No problem. I interpreted the first sentence different, however. First of all, they are not supplied with, nor, as far as I can see, does it rely directly on the Windows Phone SDK (by checking the source). That made it seem like a good candidate to your problem. As for the points: I couldn't care less :) 
Any luck sofar with your problem though?

Comment: well, I found this tool called "Tom XAP Installer". But I'm not sure if its legal to use.

Comment: @user836252:  Don't know about legality, but the first item in "Notices" says the following (and every other site from the google search referring to "Tom XAP Installer" mentions):

"Notices : 
1. Tom XAP installer Requires .NET 4.0 Framework and Windows Phone 7 SDK"

Which is not what you're looking for, right?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Windows phone will not allow the application deployment without developer unlocking the phone with the developer unlocking tool. (some people do this by hacking through registry).

After that you can use the [Windows Phone Powertools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/) to deploy the applciation when connected to Zune.

Other than this is , you have to do this by marketplace only and update the applciation.

Comment: The phone is unlocked as I said in my question. and the Windows phone Powertools needs the sdk. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can do this - just use SDK tools:

1. First of all, send him XAP Deploy, you've got it in:
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\XAP Deployment\XapDeploy.exe
2. You must unolck his phone, you can do this by your Live ID and this tool:
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\Phone Registration\PhoneReg.exe
3. Finally, he must install Zune software for conect device to PC:
   http://www.zune.net/
4. After install Zune and connect his device, just let him use XapDeploy.exe

Have fun :)