# How can i deploy an window based phone application without sdk

Tags: asp.net, windows-phone-7, deployment

I'm working on window based phone application(.xap file)

Is there any way to get the "Application Deployment" program, without installing the whole SDK?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but i think you can't do it but some alternatives can be used. Check this post : 
[Application Deployment Without SDK WP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923506/installing-aplication-deployment-without-the-sdk-windows-phone)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**  Seems this does still require the SDK.

<strike>You can use [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/)</strike>

Comment: @Pedro Lamas - You could be right.  The codeplex site doesn't specifically mention it (that I can see) but searching has turned up a few posts saying the SDK is required.